# Request parameters in PHP on HHVM

Tags: php, hhvm, hacklang

I'm running HHVM 3.2.0 and trying to get access to GET and POST request parameters. The problem is, [HHVM doesn't support access to PHP superglobals](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SERVER`, etc).

The only other way I know of getting access to request parameters in PHP is via the [filter_input](http://php.net/filter_input) function, but is that really best practice (if I'm just using the raw filter)? It seems as though HHVM should support something cleaner than that. (What about Hack?)

Comment: Does hhvm support [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I don't believe so. Not directly at least. Source: http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: Have you tried it? I'm seeing examples around using `fopen()` with `php://memory`, which "appears" to be shown as not supported on that page. Also, there's [this documentation page](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php), showing using three more listed on that page. That documentation looks pretty suspect to me.

Comment: @JaredFarrish No, but this all looks horrible. Reading request parameters is one of the principle operations of any script... How can it be so obscure?

Comment: I'm looking around and there's an awful lot of projects that seem to support hhvm. Symfony, for instance, and I can't find anything [specific to the way it's setup](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2014/05/symfony-hhvm-3-nginx-1-4-vs-php-5-5-apache-2-4/).

Comment: Do they not exist at all in HHVM? See [this post indicating that `$_POST` is available](http://hhvmhack.blogspot.com/2014/03/a-simple-tutorial.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HHVM absolutely supports superglobals in PHP code -- they're a really key part of PHP! The docs page you've linked to is simply wrong, and [I've filed a bug to get it fixed](https://github.com/hhvm/hack-hhvm-docs/issues/294).

In strict mode Hack code, superglobals are not supported; [this cookbook example](http://cookbook.hacklang.org/recipes/get-and-post/) shows how you can access them via partial mode.

Comment: since all links in this post are now dead, I can only downvote his otherwise promising answer

Comment: And how is it now inversion 4.x? How can the $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_SERVER be reached?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like they added `HH\global_get()` to get global variables.

https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/function/HH.global_get/

To put everything together

```php
use namespace \Facebook\TypeSpec;

// get $_GET using global_get
function global_get_get(): darray<arraykey, mixed> {
  $spec = TypeSpec\darray(
    TypeSpec\arraykey(),
    TypeSpec\mixed(),
  );
  return $spec->assertType(\HH\global_get("_GET"));
}
```